# activation system for flash

Tags: flash, key, offline, activation

BRIEF:

I am interested in finding out if there has been or ever will be a system for processing and managing software activation in a flash app.

DESCRIPTION:

My company develops alot in flash and flex and can already manage user access for online applications. but if I were to distribute a flash *.exe or an AIR app; are there offline serial key activation libraries available?

I have asked google and he/she says: "erm... naaah".

Answer (score 1):

Flash is pretty easy to decompile, even from an exe I believe. This won't protect your software.

Answer (score 0):

As SpliFF mentioned, it is fairly trivial to decompile SWF files, so you won't really want to store secure things there.

Also, I haven't personally used their product but [Nitro-LM](http://www.nitrolm.com) have presented at the 360|Flex conferences about their encryption / authentication software. It might fit your needs, it might not. First decent article I could find about it was on [InsideRIA](http://www.insideria.com/2008/04/encryption-in-flex-application-2.html)

Comment: Further to this Nitro-LM stuff there was a session about this product recorded last night on for the Online Flex Meetup Group

[ https://admin.adobe.acrobat.com/_a200985228/p63748890/ ] Acrobat Connect Recording